# Is it possible to prevent invocation of jQuery load callback function when returning from action method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Given the following jQuery (loading a partial view when clicking an arrow button and invoking a callback function that increments a variable):

```
    var current_number = 1;
    $("#right_arrow").click(function () {
        $("#some_partial_view").empty().load(ActionUrls.rightArrowClick, { pageNo: current_number + 1 }, function () {
            current_number++;
        })
    });
```

and the answering action method in an MVC controller:

```
    public ActionResult rightArrowClick(int number)
    {
        return PartialView("_partialView", getModel(number));
    }
```

Is it possible to prevent the load function's callback to be invoked, or, pass a parameter to it to prevent the current_number to incremented? 
I realize it's probably not a good idea to store state on the client side, but haven't found another way to do it in this particular case (#n00b).

Answer (score 1):

Could you search the responseText sent back by jQuery to your callback -

```
    var current_number = 1;
    $("#right_arrow").click(function () {
        $("#some_partial_view").empty().load(ActionUrls.rightArrowClick, { pageNo: current_number + 1 }, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if(response.indexOf('mySearchString') > -1) {
             current_number++;
            }

        })
    });
```

Obviously this will only work if there's something in your responseText that indicates the counter shouldn't be incremented.

Comment: Thanks, you wouldn't by any chance know how to add a string to the reponseText from C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a HTTP error code.